# Want to set checkbox's value into database

Tags: php

I want to set my checkbox's value into database.When I checked it ,it's value is 1 in database .If not checked it,it's value is 0.I created in checkbox but it's values aren't inserted into database.
**Here is my checkbox**

```
  バナー非表示：<input id="hide_flg" name="hide_flg"  type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($_POST['hide_flg']==1) echo "checked";?>  maxlength="15">



 function update_db($param){

        $sql = "UPDATE table SET 
        image_name = '".$this -> mysql_escape($param['image_name'])."',
        url = '',
        title = '',
        area = '',
       hide_flg='".(int)$param['hide_flg']."'
       Where statement;
 }
```

Comment: you need to set the value to 0 in javascript before making an ajax request

Comment: this cannot be all your code. Show how your post back the data, how you read the data, and how you call the update_db function including the data. P.S. Your code is likely to be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks as well, you should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to better protect your data. Just escaping strings etc is not sufficient for all scenarios.